# Command line arguments in Perl

Tags: perl

I am working on an open source project for GSoC and I have this piece of Perl code with me. I need to create another Perl file for a similar task. However, I am having trouble understanding 3 lines of this file. More specifically, I am not able to understand why the files have `$` symbol. I assume it is because they are command line arguments. However, I am not sure. I would like to have the meaning of these 3 lines explained to me.

```
open(NC, "|nc localhost 17001") || die "nc failed: $!\n";
print NC "scm hush\n(observe-text \"$_\")\n";
print "submit-one: $_\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$! and $_ are global variables. For more information you can read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm)

> $_ The default input and pattern-searching space
>
> $! If used in a numeric context, yields the current value of the errno variable, identifying the last system call error. If used in a string context, yields the corresponding system error string.

```
open(NC, "|nc localhost 17001") || die "nc failed: $!\n";
```

will run the command nc with the parameter and if it fails it will give you the error message.

Comment: The meaning of this is equals with `if($_ =~ /<P>/) ...` it will work with the next line if the actual contains `<P>`

Comment: The whole snippet is this: 
`if(/<P>/) {next;} `
`chop;`

Comment: So basically this code splits sentences from a given mass of text?